# Backbone view instantiation TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

I'm new to Backbone and I'm trying to get a basic view rendered using Underscore's templating. Here's the javascript:

```
TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function() {
      this.render();
   },
   render: function() {
      var template = _.template( $('#template').html(), {} );
      this.el.html( template );
   }
});

var test_view = new TestView( { el: $('#container') } );
```

This is the error I'm getting in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got [object Object]
```

It's throwing the error from Backbone on line 1203 (development version). You can see the error in action at [my website](http://athanclark.com/jstest).

What am I doing wrong here? Should I omit the render() function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the loading order, i.e. jQuery first:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are a god among men. I'm getting a new error now, sadly. In my render function, I'm trying to apply the compiled template to the view's el variable via the html() function, but it's telling me that el doesn't have such a function. Any ideas?

Comment: If you debug it you see that `this.el` is a plain HTML element which doesn't have `.html()` but just `.innerHTML` in case. What you want/have to do is to wrap it as a jQuery object like `$(this.el)` and then `$(this.el).html(template)` should work just fine

Comment: You're awesome Juri. Thank you so much. As a last farewell, do you happen to have any resources or articles on debugging javascript? Thank you so much again, you are a life saver.

Comment: I usually use the Chrome Dev tools, others like Firebug, it's a matter of taste. For the Chrome Dev tools I suggest you to take a look at their offical site: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/ There are a couple of interesting vids and tutorials. Paul Irish has some [nice vids as well](http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: With recent versions of Backbone you can use `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)`, no need to create something that Backbone already has.